# Index enum by string Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, types, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum QuestionType {
  text,
  recording,
  goal,
}
```

I get back one of `"Text"`, `"Recording"`, `"Goal"` back from the server (note caps).

How do I index `QuestionType` with these strings without using an `if` or `case`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/// parses string to QuestionType enum
QuestionType stringToQuestionType(String type){
    switch(type.toLowerCase()){
      case 'recording': 
        return QuestionType.recording;
      case 'goal': 
        return QuestionType.goal;
      case 'text': 
      default: 
        return QuestionType.text;
    }
  }
```

call the function by passing the string as:

```
  QuestionType questionType = stringToQuestionType('goal'); /// output: QuestionType.goal
```

Without Using `if-else` and `switch case`, you can use an extension on `String`.

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  QuestionType get toQuestionType {
    return QuestionType.values.firstWhere((e) => e.name.toLowerCase() == 'goal',
        orElse: () => QuestionType.text);
  }
}
```

and use the extension as:

```
 print('goal'.toQuestionType); /// output: QuestionType.goal
```

Comment: without using `case`

Comment: added an alternative without using `case`